# Creating multiple instances of an object. (Game)

Tags: java

I've been asked to make a game for my CS (high school) class as my end of semester assignment. We haven't been taught properly all of the coding required to make a game so my knowledge in this area is very poor. Anyways, the game I am trying to make is something like "Flappy Fall" (an Apple appstore game) where objects fall from the top of the screen and descend to the bottom of the screen. The objective is to catch these objects before they reach the bottom. I am able to get one object to fall and have also created the "catcher", but I am not sure how to create multiple falling objects, nor do I know how to remove the object once it has been caught by the catcher. So far I have classes "JavaGame", "Catcher", and "Ball". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
int x, y;
int t = 1;
private Image dbImage;
private Graphics dbGraphics;
Image player;
Image bkg;
static Catcher p = new Catcher(150, 450);

public JavaGame() {
    //Game Images
    ImageIcon b = new ImageIcon("bkg.png");
    bkg = b.getImage();

    //Game properties
    setTitle("Game");
    setSize(350, 600);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    addKeyListener(new Keys());
    addMouseMotionListener(new Mouse());


}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    //
    dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
    dbGraphics = dbImage.getGraphics();
    draw(dbGraphics);
    g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
}





public void draw(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(bkg, 0, 0, this); //Creates background
    p.draw(g);
    //while (t < 100) {
        p.b.draw(g);
        //t++;
    //}
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.drawString(""+p.score, 175, 50);
    repaint();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    JavaGame jg = new JavaGame();

    //Threads
    Thread p1 = new Thread(p);
    p1.start();
    Thread ball = new Thread(p.b);
    ball.start();
}

public class Keys extends KeyAdapter {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        p.keyPressed(e);
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        p.keyReleased(e);
    }
}

public class Mouse implements MouseMotionListener {
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        p.mouseDragged(e);
    }
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        p.mouseMoved(e);
    }
}
```

}

```
int x, y, ranX, xDirection;
int score;
Rectangle catch1;   
Ball b = new Ball(170, 1);

public Catcher (int x, int y) {
    score = 0;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    catch1 = new Rectangle(this.x, this.y, 50, 15);
}

public void run() {
    try {
        while(true) {
            move();
            Thread.sleep(5);
        }
    }

    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}


public void collision() {
    if (b.ball.intersects(catch1)) {
        b.ball(Color.blue);
        score++;
        System.out.println(score);
    }
}

public void move() {
    collision();
    catch1.x += xDirection;
    if (catch1.x <= 0)
        catch1.x = 0;
    if (catch1.x >= 300)
        catch1.x = 300; 
}

public void setXDirection(int xDir) {
    xDirection = xDir;
}

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent m) {
        int keyCode = m.getKeyCode();
        if (keyCode == m.VK_LEFT) {
            setXDirection(-1);
        }       

        if (keyCode == m.VK_RIGHT) {
            setXDirection(+1);
        }  
        m.consume();
    }            

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent m) {
        int keyCode = m.getKeyCode();
        if (keyCode == m.VK_LEFT) {
            setXDirection(0);
        }                

        if (keyCode == m.VK_RIGHT) {
            setXDirection(0);
        } 
        m.consume();
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        catch1.x = e.getX()-25;
        e.consume();
    }
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        catch1.x = e.getX()-25;
        e.consume();
    }

public void draw(Graphics g) {
    g.fillRect(catch1.x, catch1.y, catch1.width, catch1.height);

}
```

}

```
int x, y, yDirection;
Rectangle ball;

public Ball (int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    ball = new Rectangle(this.x, this.y, 10, 10);
}

public void run() {
    try{
        while(true) {
            move();
            Thread.sleep(5);
        }
    }

    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}

public void move() {
    if (ball.y >= 600) {
        ball.y = 600;
    }

    if (ball.y > 0) {
        ball.y++;
    }
}

public void setYDirection(int yDir) {
    yDirection = yDir;
}

public void draw(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(ball.x, ball.y, ball.width, ball.height);
    System.out.println(ball.x+ " "+ ball.y+ " " + ball.width + " " + ball.height);
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

I'd re-organize the code a little.  In the main game, you can have a collection of 'Ball' types.  I'll leave the collection option up to you.  But you'll want to add 'new' Balls to the collection and then remove them once they are caught.

Answer (score 2):

Since I do not want to do your assignment, I am just giving a short answer:

By calling `new Ball()` multiple times.
Of course you might want to add them to a collection, like
     List list = new ArrayList();
     list.add(ball);

And remove them from that collection once they are finished.